# Ubuntu 18.04 does not connect to Android smartphone

Tags: usb, bluetooth, android

Neither Bluetooth connection nor USB connection is able to transfer files from Android smartphone to Ubuntu 18.04. Same devices with Ubuntu 16.04 did not show any problems. When starting Nautilus, it shows the android device, but when opening it, it stays busy and does not show any results.

Ubuntu 18.04 kernel: 4.15.0-20-generic
Android Smartphone Samsung A3, Android 7.0

kernel.log messages when connecting the phone via USB seems to be OK:

```
May 12 05:39:53 len kernel: [69577.277832] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device    number 28 using xhci_hcd
May 12 05:39:53 len kernel: [69577.427116] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=6860
May 12 05:39:53 len kernel: [69577.427122] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
May 12 05:39:53 len kernel: [69577.427127] usb 2-1: Product: SAMSUNG_Android
May 12 05:39:53 len kernel: [69577.427130] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: SAMSUNG
May 12 05:39:53 len kernel: [69577.427134] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 5203f8dd51fc142b
```

When starting Nautilus from shell and opening Android folder, I get the following message:

```
Nautilus-Share-Message: 05:41:13.818: Called "net usershare info" but it failed:  
Childprocess »net« could not be executed (No such file or directory)
```

My workarround at the moment: installing SSHHelper on Android and using scp to copy files via SSH.

Comment: do you have mtp-tools installed? phone is unlocked?

Comment: I just tested my Samsung phone on both USB and Bluetooth and both worked without issue. No additional software or configuration required.

Comment: Not a solution, but Kubuntu 18.04 comes with kde connect that integrates android phones with desktop when connected to the same wifi.

Comment: installing mtp-tool does not help. On phone a popup asks for giving access, it is granted. I have added some error/warnings to the questiion above. Maybe they help to solve the problem.

Comment: Same with Asus tablet on kubuntu

Comment: kde connect over WIFI worked, though.

Comment: ... and it doesn't allow the file transfer I want. f*ck.

Comment: I have the same issue. I ended up adding the app FTP Server to the phone, then using Filezilla on Ubuntu to transfer files back-and-forth. That app was the only one that allowed me to copy from the PC to the phone, though some others would let me download from the phone to the PC. Unfortunately, it doesn't support TLS/SSL yet, but on the bright side, there's no cable needed...

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem with ubuntu 18.04 lts and a samsung s6 edge. When I connect the phone to my pc and open Nautilus it shows no files or folders. But I stumbled on a work around: close all instances of Nautilus, dismount the phone and turn it off without disconecting it. Then turn it on and sometimes Nautilus can see it. Hope it works for you

Comment: Connecting my Samsung A3 to Kubuntu 18.04 over USB was not working, also solved by connecting the phone and then restarting it while still connected. Using Dolphin rather than Nautilus since kubuntu rather than gnome, did not have to close any instances of Dolphin, just restarting the phone was enough.

Answer (score 1):

On the phone, you have to click on the notification that says "use this USB for charging" and change it to file transfer.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, I tried this and worked, check:

Ubuntu Linux: There are two things that need to be set up correctly: each user that wants to use adb needs to be in the plugdev group, and the system needs to have udev rules installed that cover the device.

plugdev group: If you see an error message that says you're not in the plugdev group, you'll need to add yourself to the plugdev group:

```
sudo usermod -aG plugdev $LOGNAME
```

Note that groups only get updated on login, so you'll need to log out for this change to take effect. When you log back in, you can use id to check that you're now in the plugdev group.

udev rules: The android-sdk-platform-tools-common package contains a community-maintained default set of udev rules for Android devices. To install:

```
apt-get install android-sdk-platform-tools-common
```

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device

Answer (score 1):

My experience shows me that the main culprit is often the cable or the usb port, which cause a faulty or dropping connection. When I happen to have these problems, often a new cable or the original one resolve the issue.

Comment: In my case the Usb 3.0 entrance was not working. When I plugged the cable to a 2.0 usb entrance it worked.