# 18.04 won't recognize device and attempts to get it to recognize it have failed

Tags: apt, usb, dpkg

I'm trying to get 18.04 to recognize a cell phone with some videos and photos on it and when I plug it in to the USB port nothing happens. I can't see that any new device has been added. Upon researching this problem I found that the command 'sudo apt-get install hware info' is supposed to fix this. When I tried using it I got a "dpkg was interrupted" error. After manually running  'sudo dpkg - configure-a' to correct the problem, I tried the hware command again two times with the device in the USB port. Still no change. Please advise and thanks in advance.

See what I did below:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034919/ubuntu-18-04-does-not-connect-to-android-smartphone try this if your phone is based on Android. You can also send photos and videos via online storage e.g. google drive, dropbox and etc.

Comment: Thanks! By accident I left the phone plugged in to the laptop and just turned it on and off a couple times and now it is showing up as a device but it isn't showing any files or folders containing the pictures (or anything for that matter). I wonder why that is?

Comment: Smartphones and especially iPhones have a black-box which prevents a reverse engineering (analyze-what's-inside) and security issue, that protects you and us from ill-mannered users. We lose a little liberty of phones and as a result, phones can't be cloned except a smartphone vender. If your phone and computer are connected to WiFi, I suggest transfer files via online-storage. Every few months, phone OS updates and Ubuntu team can't catch up protocols of USB connection to it. "Yes, that was available a year ago!"

Comment: I ended up calling Motorola and they figured it out. I just hadn't gone deeply enough into the settings of the phone to find the camera files and open them. As soon as I did that, Ubuntu responded and the files were transferred without any need to use "the cloud".